# Conky widget looks bad

Tags: 16.04, conky

I'm trying to install Malice-tab-conky, but many errors occur. I already fixed problems with hddtemp, font and missing $endif. Right now it kinda works, but looks something like this:

[image]

When running Conky here's the output from terminal:

```
conky: desktop window (240000a) is subwindow of root window (f5)
conky: window type - override
conky: drawing to created window (0x3600001)
conky: drawing to double buffer
conky: unknown variable '$pre_exec'
```

And last but not least here's the code from `.conkyrc`:

```
conky.config = {
--########################################
-- Modified by : http://www.NoobsLab.com #
--########################################
--#####################
-- - Conky settings - #
--#####################
    update_interval = 1,
    total_run_times = 0,
    net_avg_samples = 1,
    cpu_avg_samples = 1,

    imlib_cache_size = 0,
    double_buffer = true,
    no_buffers = true,
    format_human_readable = true,
    draw_graph_borders = false,

--####################
-- - Text settings - #
--####################
    use_xft = true,
    font = 'Calibri:normal:size=9',
    override_utf8_locale = true,
    text_buffer_size = 2048,

--############################
-- - Window specifications - #
--############################
    own_window_class = 'Conky',
    own_window = true,
    own_window_type = 'override',
    own_window_transparent = true,
    own_window_hints = 'undecorated,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager',

    alignment = 'middle_right',
    gap_x = -35,
    gap_y = 0,
    minimum_width = 182, minimum_height = 600,
    maximum_width = 182,

    default_bar_width = 60, default_bar_height = 8,

--########################
-- - Graphics settings - 6
--########################
    draw_shades = false,

    default_color = '6D6D6D',

    color0 = '6D6D6D',
    color1 = 'red',
    color2 = '6D6D6D',

--###############
-- - Load Lua - #
--###############
    lua_load = '~/.conky/Malice-Tab/scripts/bargraph_small.lua',
    lua_draw_hook_post = 'main_bars',

};

conky.text = [[
########################
# - Background Image - #
########################
${image ~/.conky/Malice-Tab/images/bg.png -p 0,0 -s 147x489} 
###############
# - Network - #
###############
${goto 50}${voffset 10}${font Calibri Bold Caps:size=8} Network${font}
${goto 60}${voffset 7}DL
${goto 60}${voffset 5}UL
${goto 60}${voffset 3}IP     ${if_up wlan0}${addr wlan0}${endif}${if_up eth0}${addr eth0}${endif}
##############
# - Memory - #
##############
${goto 50}${voffset 10}${font Calibri Bold Caps:size=8} Memory${font}

${goto 78}${voffset 5}Ram ${goto 120}${memperc}%
${goto 78}${voffset 15}Swap ${goto 120}${swapperc}%
###########
# - CPU - #
###########
${goto 45}${voffset 20}${font Calibri Bold Caps:size=8} CPU${font}
${goto 50}${voffset 5}Processor${goto 120}${cpu cpu}%
${goto 78}${voffset -5}${cpugraph cpu0 20,70 }
${goto 48}${voffset -3}Running:  ${running_processes}
${goto 50}${voffset -3}${top name 1}${top mem 1} ${top cpu 1}
${goto 50}${voffset -3}${top name 2}${top mem 2} ${top cpu 2}
${goto 50}${voffset -3}${top name 3}${top mem 3} ${top cpu 3}
${goto 50}${voffset -3}${top name 4}${top mem 4} ${top cpu 4}
##############
# - System - #
##############
${goto 50}${voffset 17}${font Calibri Bold Caps:size=8} System${font}
${goto 55}${font Lucida Grande:size=7}✖ ${font}${pre_exec cat /etc/issue.net}
${goto 55}${font Lucida Grande:size=7}✖ ${font}${kernel}
${goto 55}${font Lucida Grande:size=7}✖ ${font}Uptime: ${uptime_short}
${goto 55}${font Lucida Grande:size=7}✖ ${font}HDD Temp: ${hddtemp /dev/sda} °C
${goto 55}${font Lucida Grande:size=7}✖ ${font}Core Temp: ${execi 8 sensors | grep -A 1 'temp1' | cut -c16-17 | sed '/^$/d'} °C

##############
# - System - #
############## 
${goto 50}${voffset 15}${font Calibri Bold Caps:size=8} Hard Drive${font}
${goto 120}${voffset 10}${fs_used_perc /}%
${goto 60}${voffset -12}Root:
${goto 120}${voffset 18}${fs_used_perc /home}%
${goto 60}${voffset -12}Home:
]];
```

I've tried to play with different parameters, but nothing seems to refer to size of the widget (only positioning).
How can I fix this?

Comment: Look at these two lines: `minimum_width = 182, minimum_height = 600,
    maximum_width = 182,` On my 1920x1080 screen I have maximum set at 400 and font size changed from about 9 to about 11 I think. Plus Unity Tweak Tool text scaling factor is set to 1.5 to account for hdpi.

Comment: Thanks @WinEunuuchs2Unix for fast reply. When changing max to 400 nothing seems to happen at all. And Unity Tweak Tool doesn't work either: font of the system becomes bigger, but widget stays the same.